# in wcf service not able to get the wsdl

Tags: wcf

i have an service been hosted in iis  7, in windows7 when i type the url
http://192.160.11.13/Employee/Service1.svc 
i can see the below information.

svcutil.exe http://192.160.11.13/Employee/Service1.svc?wsdl

```
This will generate a configuration file and a code file that contains the client class. Add the two files to your client application and use the generated client class to call the Service. For example:

C#

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Service1Client client = new Service1Client();

        // Use the 'client' variable to call operations on the service.

        // Always close the client.
        client.Close();
    }
}
```

when i type to get the wsdl  http://192.160.11.13/Employee/Service1.svc?wsdl
i am not getting the wsdl  instead i am getting this error message
HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

what i am missing here, please let me know so that i can generate the wsdl

Thanks
Prince

Comment: Can you post your web.config and hosting code for the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is http 404, which means "file not found".

There could be several reasons for this:

- The service is not running
- httpget is not allowed in the web.config
- the mex endpoint is not set up in the web.config
- you are not wusing the correct url

Before you use the svcutil make sure that you can access the wsdl file through the browser.

Comment: OP indicated he was hosting in IIS and that he was able to browse to the service's help page.   A 404 error is most likely an incorrect URL.  Hard to say anything more definitive without seeing his config file.